# How to calculate the cost basis of a company share that was received in an acquisition? (UK)

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

This is something I've been wondering about for some time now, and I think it's best if I explain my question through an example (I'm going to make this example hypothetical and very extreme just to make my point):

- Suppose I buy 10 shares in company X for £10 each (making my total
  investment £100)
- The shares of company X go up in value to £12 each
  the next day
- The company X is acquired by company Y the day after
- My
  10 shares of company X are now replaced with 20 shares of company Y,
  each with a market value of £10

What would be the cost basis of a single one of these shares from company Y? It would be my assumption that it should be £5 (the total cost basis of the original shares from company X (£100) divided by the number of shares received in company Y (20))

Is this correct? I would really appreciate insight into a situation like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption would be correct. See [this article](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=5ac9eebc-8bf0-4fcb-9b99-f37d8114bea3) that talks about taxation of corporate events in the UK, and specifically discusses the scenario you're describing:

> For tax purposes, where a target shareholder exchanges its shares for new shares as part of an acquisition, the shareholder is not treated as having made a disposal of the old holding for the purposes of capital gains tax provided certain conditions are met (share-for-share exchange relief). *Instead, the shareholder is treated as having acquired the new holding at the same time, and for the same consideration, as the old holding*.